# How to get child blocks the same size as their parent

Tags: css, hover, nav

Short version shows better in picture :

[image: Example]

I want to create a navbar which shows blocks when hovered on, but can't get around how to get the child element to be the size of its parent. I'd like Item 1.1, ... to be the same width of Item 1 and so on, while on the example displayed below, you'll see this doesn't work for a reason I can't seem to comprehend.

```css
#menu{
    width: 60%;
    min-width: 500px;
    height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 10px auto 15px auto;
}
#menu li{
    width: calc(100% / 5 - 1%);
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
}
#menu li a{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background-color:#fff;
    font-family: Helvetica Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
    font-size: 0.7em;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #6E4712;
    border: 2px solid rgba(127,201,154, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu li a:hover{
    color: rgba(127,201,154, 0.5);
}
#menu .sous-menu{ 
    display: none;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
#menu .sous-menu li{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
}
#menu .sous-menu li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Helvetica Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
    font-size: 0.7em;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #6E4712;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu .sous-menu li a:hover{
    color: rgba(127,201,154, 0.5);
}
#menu li:hover .sous-menu{ 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
                    <ul class="sous-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1.3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1.4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Sorry for the code being exhausting to read but I tend to repeat myself, being new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I have added **padding: 0;** to **#menu .sous-menu** and removed **position: absolute;** in **#menu li:hover .sous-menu**. This should work:

```css
#menu{
    width: 60%;
    min-width: 500px;
    height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 10px auto 15px auto;
}
#menu li{
    width: calc(100% / 5 - 1%);
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
}
#menu li a{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background-color:#fff;
    font-family: Helvetica Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
    font-size: 0.7em;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #6E4712;
    border: 2px solid rgba(127,201,154, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu li a:hover{
    color: rgba(127,201,154, 0.5);
}
#menu .sous-menu{ 
    display: none;
    margin-top: -2px;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu .sous-menu li{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
}
#menu .sous-menu li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Helvetica Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
    font-size: 0.7em;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #6E4712;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu .sous-menu li a:hover{
    color: rgba(127,201,154, 0.5);
}
#menu li:hover .sous-menu{ 
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I do agree that it then works by itself, but the point of the "position: absolute" was to have it over other elements that aren't positioned. Is it possible while keeping the absolute value?

Comment: if "position: absolute" is needed, you will have to specify the width, e.g., `#menu li:hover .sous-menu{ 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(61.5% / 5 - 1%);
}`

Comment: Ooooh. That works perfectly at 62%, 61.5% seems just a bit off. Thanks a lot! May I ask what's the math you did here?  Is that due to the width at 60% on #menu ?

Comment: Yes. With "position: absolute", the containing block changes so it is a bit off. Here is a link to more info in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block).